# How to get elements inside an array inside an array in JSON using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am able to get some information from a JSON page, however I am struggling to get elements inside an array which is inside an array.

My code so far:

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     try {
         String status = response.getString("status");

         if (status.equals("ok")) {
             JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");
             JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
             titleTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("title"));
         }

     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

The page in which I receive the JSON is: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=trump&language=en&apiKey=954cfe1dd4db4f8fb19e425c12db324e

My code so far gets my the first article's information, except from the array called "source"

I am looking to get the information in the array called "source" named "name"

Comment: `source` is not `JSONArray` its `JSONObject`, check my answer hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"source"` is not `JSONArray` its `JSONObject`

to get the `name` from `source` Object try this

```
if (status.equals("ok")) {
   JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONObject sourceObject= jsonObject.getJSONObject("source");
   titleTextView.setText(sourceObject.getString("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the  https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=trump&language=en&apiKey=954cfe1dd4db4f8fb19e425c12db324e api, source is an object instead of an array.
You can easily access the 'name' in 'source' object by parsing the object and getting the string value corresponding to the 'name' key in it.

```
@Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
 try {
     String status = response.getString("status");

     if (status.equals("ok")) {
         JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");
         JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
         titleTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("title"));

         JSONObject source = jsonObject.getJSONObject("source");
         sourceNameTextView.setText(source.getString("name"));
     }

 } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}